# Intercepting all UI events in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

Is there a way to intercept all the UI (touch/click etc) events in the browser (for monitoring/debugging etc) - in JavaScript code and in any Chrome tools - all goes. As an example, I want to mark some event (by adding some property) and catch it when it is handled (even more than once) to see the stack trace etc

**Update:** Looking for intercept every event *even if is not* propagated (bubbled/captured) somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the list of event types from the `Event` constructor.

```
Object.keys(Event).forEach(function (etype) {
    document.addEventListener(
        etype.toLowerCase(), console.log.bind(console), false
    );
});
```

The event type constants exposed by the [`Event` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event) are the following (in the desktop Safari):

```
["MOUSEOUT", "FOCUS", "CHANGE", "MOUSEMOVE",
 "SELECT", "BLUR", "KEYUP",   "MOUSEDOWN", "MOUSEDRAG",
 "MOUSEUP", "MOUSEOVER", "CLICK", "DBLCLICK",
 "KEYDOWN", "KEYPRESS", "DRAGDROP"]
```

Comment: what if a particular event is not propagated (bubbled/captured) somewhere in the code (question edited)?

Comment: @BreakPhreak, then you can use WebInspector. See the Timelines tab, JavaScript & Events panel. It logs all subscribed event handlers.

Comment: just tried it on this page (clicked on up/down arrows above the points' number for your answer) - looks like it works! :)